# Copying a folder while taking into account file overlap before computing if there's enough storage space to copy the files (or don't even check it)

Tags: windows, file-management

I am looking for a program running on Windows 10 that can recursively copy a folder while taking into account file overlap before computing if there's enough storage space to copy the files (or don't even check if there's enough storage space). E.g., if the destination folder already has 40% of the content from the origin folder, that 40% shouldn't be included when computing if there's enough storage space.

Any license and price is fine, but I want a GUI and I use Windows 10.

---

What I've tried:

Both Windows Explorer and [[Explorer++](https://explorerplusplus.com/) check if there's enough storage space but ignores file overlap:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`robocopy` (gratis, CLI, comes with Windows 10) can recursively copy a folder without caring about the remaining storage space. It'll skip files that have already been copied. To use, open `cmd.exe` and run:

```
robocopy /e source_folder destination_folder
```

e.g.

```
robocopy /e "C:\big folder" "E:\temp"
```

---

From the [robocopy manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy):

> - `/e`: Copies subdirectories. This option automatically includes empty directories.